# Am I using plyr right? I seem to be using way too much memory

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I have the following, somewhat large dataset:

```
 > dim(dset)
 [1] 422105     25
 > class(dset)
 [1] "data.frame"
 >
```

Without doing anything, the R process seems to take about 1GB of RAM.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
  dset <- ddply(dset, .(tic), transform,
                date.min <- min(date),
                date.max <- max(date),
                daterange <- max(date) - min(date),
                .parallel = TRUE)
```

Running that code, RAM usage skyrockets. It completely saturated 60GB's of RAM, running on a 32 core machine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a quick follow up, I tried this with a much smaller subset of the data, and RAM usage still shot up to 17 GB

Comment: the `<-` look funny to me.  What happens if you use `=` within the parentheses instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If performance is an issue, it might be a good idea to switch to using `data.table`s from the package of the same name. They are *fast*. You'd do something roughly equivalent something like this:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(100),
                  dt = seq.Date(as.Date('2010-01-01'),as.Date('2011-01-01'),length.out = 100),
                  grp = rep(letters[1:4],each = 25))

dt <- as.data.table(dat)
key(dt) <- "grp"

dt[,mutate(.SD,date.min = min(dt),
               date.max = max(dt),
               daterange = max(dt) - min(dt)), by = grp]
```

Comment: +1 -- I'll second that.  I just did timings on a `plyr` and a slightly different `data.table` solution with 30000 levels of `tic`. `ddply` took 247.80 seconds to `data.table`'s 3.75 seconds.  In addition, `data.table` is also designed to use less memory, implementing pass-by-reference instead of memory consumptive pass-by-value for data.frames.

Comment: mutate(.SD,... should be changed to with(.SD,list(date.min = min(dt),... to get right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. Trying with my dataset right now on a more modest machine (core i5, 6GB RAM)

Comment: @stevejb Be sure to try out Josh's strategy too, I just slapped together a quick example for illustration; his will probably perform better.

Comment: @joran I did that. Pretty cool code. I gave you the answer since you answered first, but my code is based on Josh's. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Here's an alternative application of `data.table` to the problem, illustrating how blazing-fast it can be. (Note: this uses `dset`, the `data.frame` constructed by Brian Diggs in his answer, except with 30000 rather than 10 levels of `tic`).

(The reason this is much faster than @joran's solution, is that it avoids the use of `.SD`, instead using the columns directly. The style's a bit different than `plyr`, but it typically buys huge speed-ups. For another example, see the [`data.table` Wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages%3acran%3adata.table) which: (a) includes this as recommendation #1 ; and (b) shows a 50X speedup for code that drops the `.SD`).

```
library(data.table)
system.time({
    dt <- data.table(dset, key="tic")
    # Summarize by groups and store results in a summary data.table
    sumdt <- dt[ ,list(min.date=min(date), max.date=max(date)), by="tic"]
    sumdt[, daterange:= max.date-min.date]
    # Merge the summary data.table back into dt, based on key
    dt <- dt[sumdt]
})
# ELAPSED TIME IN SECONDS
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.45    0.25    1.77
```

Comment: This is indeed blazingly fast. For my dataset, 2.621 sec of elapsed time. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things come to mind.

First, I would write it as:

```
dset <- ddply(dset, .(tic), summarise,
                date.min = min(date),
                date.max = max(date),
                daterange = max(date) - min(date),
                .parallel = TRUE)
```

Well, actually, I would probably avoid double calculating min/max date and write

```
dset <- ddply(dset, .(tic), function(DF) {
              mutate(summarise(DF, date.min = min(date),
                               date.max = max(date)),
                     daterange = date.max - date.min)},
              .parallel = TRUE)
```

but that's not the main point you are asking about.

With a dummy data set of your dimensions

```
n <- 422105
dset <- data.frame(date=as.Date("2000-01-01")+sample(3650, n, replace=TRUE),
    tic = factor(sample(10, n, replace=TRUE)))
for (i in 3:25) {
    dset[i] <- rnorm(n)
}
```

this ran comfortably (sub 1 minute) on my laptop.  In fact the `plyr` step took less time than creating the dummy data set.  So it couldn't have been swapping to the size you saw.

A second possibility is if there are a large number of unique values of `tic`.  That could increase the size needed.  However when I tried it increasing the possible number of unique `tic` values to 1000, it didn't really slow down.

Finally, it could be something in the parallelization.  I don't have a parallel backend registered for `foreach`, so it was just doing a serial approach.  Perhaps that is causing your memory explosion.

Comment: There are about 30000 levels of tic. I read the JSS article on plyr, and it said that it was careful not to make extra copies of the data. That is why the memory usage was so surprising.

Comment: @stevejb: I've had a similar experience; plyr doesn't seem to cope well with large numbers of classification levels (about 25000 in my case). I eventually went back to base R's `split` and `tapply` which did the job, albeit in a much more cumbersome way.

Comment: It's because plyr uses data frames internally, which are unfortunately slow and memory hogs.

Answer (score 1):

Are there many numbers of factor levels in the data frame?  I've found that this type of excessive memory usage is common in adply and possibly other plyr functions, but can be remedied by removing unnecessary factors and levels. If the large data frame was read into R, make sure stringsAsFactors is set to FALSE in the import:

```
dat = read.csv(header=TRUE, sep="\t", file="dat.tsv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then assign the factors you actually need.

I haven't look into Hadley's source yet to discover why.