# ddply memory requirements, solutions

Tags: r, memory, count, plyr

I have a column, and in that column I have about 5-10 instances each of a few hundred thousand different strings. I want to count them and then put the counts into the corresponding lines. So I do:

```
newdf <-  ddply(oldDF, ~BigVariable, transform, counts = length(BigVariable))
```

That works fine until I start approaching 1 million rows/1GB file size. 
My R session is crashing with a fatal error every time with a dataset of this size or larger. However with 28 Gb of free memory, I don't see why that should be a problem, but my understanding from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454019/am-i-using-plyr-right-i-seem-to-be-using-way-too-much-memory) is that ddply can sometimes be a memory hog.

I'm pretty sure it is a memory issue though, because prior to the crash on my system monitor I see the modified memory and in use memory fighting over the free memory until the green bar triumphs and takes the last bit, with R crashing at that same moment.

- I have done the obvious and used data.table for more efficient memory use.
- There are a massive number of factors in one variable. I tried changing the offending variable to a character in the hopes it would make better use of data.table, but no dice.

What else should I try? Is there a more memory efficient way to get these counts and put them in all the appropriate rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` is a better alternative to `ddply` as it can be more efficient.

```
library(dplyr)
oldDF %>%
     group_by(BigVariable) %>%
     mutate(counts = n())
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(oldDF)[, counts := .N, by = BigVariable]
```

Comment: The first solution completed without crashing, but gave me a NULL. The second appears to have worked well. Now, to see how big a dataset I can push this to. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesHanks The NULL output is perplexing.  Have you tried it on a fresh session.